# Max concurrent instances of a NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a function that calls an API with `NSURLSessionDataTask` you can see it here:

```
- (void)getExplorerUrl:(void (^)(NSString *))measurement_url {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.ooni.io/api/v1/measurements?report_id=%@&input=%@", self.report_id, self.url_id.url];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            NSArray *resultsArray = [dic objectForKey:@"results"];
            if ([resultsArray count] == 0)
                measurement_url(nil);
            measurement_url([[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"measurement_url"]);
        }
        else {
            // Fail
            measurement_url(nil);
            NSLog(@"error : %@", error.description);
        }
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

This function uses a completion handler to return a value when the async call is finished.

Now I want a for cycle to loop many objects and call this API for every object:

```
    for (Measurement *measurement in [Measurement measurementsWithJson]){
        [measurement getExplorerUrl:^(NSString *measurement_url) {
            if (measurement_url != nil){
                //Do something
                NSLog(@"%@ measurement_url %@",measurement.Id, measurement_url);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"%@ measurement_url null", measurement.Id);
            }
        }];
    }
```

Is there a way to set a max concurrent async calls to 10? And then execute the next call as soon as one call finishes.

Comment: You’re using the `sharedSession` and it will default to 6 concurrent requests in macOS. If you really want 10 instead of 6, create your own `URLSession` instance, setting the [`HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407597-httpmaximumconnectionsperhost?language=objc) for your `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object that you supply when instantiating your own session object. But your code will run them concurrently already, so there’s not much else you want to do (unless you wanted to throttle it a bit to avoid timeouts).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Rob that he can create his own configuration for `URLSession`. However, if this `sharedSession` is used across different jobs and he wanted this job to run with max concurrent async calls to 10, I would suggest to use either `NSOperationQueue` or `dispatch_semaphore` to solve this problem. Please refer to the example below to have draftily understand on these approaches

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 10;

for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"[Q] %d", i);
        sleep(1);
    }];
}
```

or

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_queue_create("q.q", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_semaphore_t s = dispatch_semaphore_create(10);
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    dispatch_async(q, ^{
        NSLog(@"[Q] %d", i);
        sleep(1);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(s);
    });

}
```

You can observe from the console to see the results. Basically the 2 approaches will perform maximum 10 calls at the same time, and as long as one finished, others will be enter to the execution queue.

I hope this will help you to address your problem. Can have any discussion as needed.!!!

Comment: A few observations: First, if you’re using `sharedSession`, the `NSURLSession` still will only do max of 6 (on macOS) concurrent requests per host. Using dispatch/operation queues to constrain degree of concurrency to 10 won’t increase that. `NSURLSession` will still be the limiting factor. Second, while I get what you’re trying to say on the operation queue, in this pattern, you have to wrap requests in asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass (not hard, but more involved than what you’ve shared here). Third, with semaphore example, signaling without waiting somewhere doesn’t accomplish anything.

Comment: I get your point here. As I said, maybe his intention was about how to get max concurrent call is 10, then I post the code to help him, and for the second code, yes he has to wait the semaphore in the dispatch queue to ensure all tasked finished to complete it. I can edit my post to add it. Let see what he wants us to help him out. If I misunderstand somewhere, then I will remove/revise my post.